# LEFT JOIN even if empty SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my DB two tables :
Advices and Votes

an advice can have 0 or many votes

I'd like to get all advices validated order by the notoriety :

```
SELECT advices.*, COUNT(upvotes.id) - COUNT(downvotes.id) AS notoriety 
FROM `advices` 
LEFT JOIN votes AS upvotes ON upvotes.is_good=1 AND upvotes.advice_id=advices.id 
LEFT JOIN votes AS downvotes ON downvotes.is_good=0 AND downvotes.advice_id=advices.id 
WHERE `advices`.`subject_id` = 1
AND `advices`.`state` = 'validated' 
ORDER BY notoriety ASC
```

But, the result only show advices with votes ! What should I change to have advices without vote too ?

Thanks

Comment: You need a group by. (Or use sub-selects to count.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead of two joins:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       (SUM(downvotes.is_good = 1) - SUM(downvotes.is_good = 0) ) AS notoriety 
FROM advices a LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON a.id = v.advice_id
WHERE a.`subject_id` = 1 AND a.`state` = 'validated' 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY notoriety ASC;
```

You can get your version to work using `count(distinct)` rather than `count()`.  However, the above version is simpler and should perform better.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you're having a problem is that the count is returning null where no votes exist. You can use the NVL function to replace those null's with 0.

```
SELECT advices.*, nvl(COUNT(upvotes.id),0) - nvl(COUNT(downvotes.id),0) AS notoriety 
FROM `advices` 
LEFT JOIN votes AS upvotes ON upvotes.is_good=1 AND upvotes.advice_id=advices.id 
LEFT JOIN votes AS downvotes ON downvotes.is_good=0 AND downvotes.advice_id=advices.id 
WHERE `advices`.`subject_id` = 1
AND `advices`.`state` = 'validated' 
ORDER BY notoriety ASC
```

Comment: The question is about MySQL, not Oracle. And `COUNT()` never returns `null` anyway.